# Naming convention best practices to avoid eslint no-shadow rule in functional React component

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I have a simple functional react component which is utilizing hooks.

```
const TagTree = props => {
  const [treeData, setTreeData] = useState(props.tagData);
  const handleTreeChange = *treeData* => setTreeData(treeData);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTreeData(treeData);
  }, [treeData]);

  return (
    <div style={{ height: '100%' }} key="TagTree">
      <SortableTree
        canDrag={false}
        treeData={treeData}
        onChange={*treeData* => handleTreeChange(treeData)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

This works, however, eslint is showing I am violating the no-shadow rule for **treeData** in the `handleTreeChange` method, and inside the `onChange` as deliminated by the **.

I understand why this may be an issue, and thus want to ask what a proper naming convention to change this to would be.  I was thinking of using *treeDataArg* but that sounds a bit strange as I've never suffixed a variable name with *Arg*.

Thanks a bunch for any input on best practices here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your variable naming is totally valid. I wouldn't rename anything, but rather call the `setTreeData` function in a more direct way:

First change: Remove the function `handleTreeChange`, it has the exact same signature as `setTreeData`.

```
const TagTree = props => {
  const [treeData, setTreeData] = useState(props.tagData);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTreeData(treeData);
  }, [treeData]);

  return (
    <div style={{ height: '100%' }} key="TagTree">
      <SortableTree
        canDrag={false}
        treeData={treeData}
        onChange={treeData => setTreeData(treeData)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Second change: `treeData => setTreeData(treeData)` is a function that takes treeData and passing it to another function that takes treeData. As the signature is the same, you can pass `setTreeData` directly:

```
const TagTree = props => {
  const [treeData, setTreeData] = useState(props.tagData);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTreeData(treeData);
  }, [treeData]);

  return (
    <div style={{ height: '100%' }} key="TagTree">
      <SortableTree
        canDrag={false}
        treeData={treeData}
        onChange={setTreeData}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

I think the fact that all those functions are doing the same thing lead to the name conflicts.
By the way, what are you trying to achieve with useEffect?

Comment: David, this is great advice. Using it, I have just simplified the component and removed the naming issue completely. Next time I see this eslint issue, I will assume I have redundant code that can be fixed. Extremely helpful. 

As for why I am using useEffect, this component was recieving new props from its parent, but not rerendering. Using the useEffect seemed to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

React isn't very opinionated about most variable names.  They do suggest the `const [name, setName] = useState()` variable naming, for example, but don't talk about other functional variable names.  In my experience, I think something like `newTreeData` or `treeDataInput` seem logical.

Comment: Thank you Larz! It is great to know that a name like `newTreeData` is a logical naming convention if the circumstance calls for it. Will be remembering this moving forward.